# How do I get the total height of all items inside an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, uwp, itemscontrol

I've tried accessing rendersize, actualheight, height, nothing is providing height of all items inside my ItemsControl element - in fact the only property returning a value is ItemsControl.ActualHeight; however this is returning the same size as the parent StackPanel element, which is nested inside a grid.

Is there any way to calculate or pull the full height of an ItemsControl element with all Items generated/rendered? Currently if my window renders at 1920x1080 and I've got a ton of items in my ItemsControl - the ItemsControl actualHeight always matches the windows height; I need to be able to determine the full length of all my items and how it compares to the window size.

Thanks really appreciate your time and assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ItemsControls are complicated entities, you see, there is progressive/incremental loading built in to those controls, it is part of a system called **Virtualization**, and it an extremely widespread across all UI systems, when you scroll down on BinGooglGo image results you get progressive loading for example.

Not all items inside the **ItemSource** are rendered at the same time, instead only what the user sees have a 'physical' form.

It is often for example that, A typical UWP **ListView** will only render the exact amount of items that fit into the current **ViewPort** (visible area) plus about 10-20 more items south and north of of the viewport in preparation of a scrolling action.

Edit:
But because i dont like leaving my answers not being solutions, i will showcase the following albeit Anti-Pattern :

Wrap your ItemsControl with a Scrollviewer, it will cause an immediate load of all of its contents.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response! Now forgive my ItemsControl noobness… but by wrap it around a Scrollviewer; do you mean put the scrollviewer in the datatemplate? ItemTemplate?

Comment: i mean put your list inside a scrollviewer, let me know how it works.

Comment: Working better thanks! Still pretty new to xaml, but it's growing on me. What I've got going on is a visual element that's bound to an observableCollection (ItemsControl). My goal was to make a scroller class that takes this element and scrolls it seamlessly on display - it's does this by duplicating the xaml elements and animating the renderTransformationOrigin; scrolls one up the view, soon as the bottom of that list reaches the bottom of my view it tells the duplicate to start animating. They call each other in a chain of responsibility style until the scrolling state changes

Comment: oh ok, sounds like you might need to use the WinRTXamltookit.uwp to acquire the emended scrollview that already exists inside the itemscontrol, also the indows Community Toolkit has approachable encapsulations of animations.

Comment: Everything is working with one exception... The cloned itemsControl I'm dynamically adding in the code behind (in my custom scroller class) adds it to my parent Canvas - but the ActualHeight is 0 after the Load event fires; renderSize is also zero; so my guess is the parent element hasn't yet drawn the new child element? You're thoughts? I've come this far and got so close without the toolkit my puzzle solving side wants to figure this out lol...

Comment: Ah called UpdateLayout on the canvas after adding the child element! fixed it. Scrolling now :D